SpringBoot and jasypt encrypt at startup or as command line tool
I have a SpringBoot application which uses JASYPT to use encrypted properties.
I am trying to find a way to encrypt values in a additional (external) property file at startup or runtime. Like spring.datasource.password. The documentation is often mentioning to use mvn, but in my scenario the data comes from the customer at runtime. There is no maven installed to use the jasypt plugin.
So I am wondering how to implement it into the application itself. First idea was to implement a ApplicationRunner go through all property files and decrypt all values containing the pattern key=DEC(value). But for keys like spring.datasource.password this approach does not work, since SpringBoot will not boot up, because of failing to connect to the DB - since the password is not working. The ApplicationRunner is executed to late for this approach.
Is there a ways to decrypt the values before SpringBoot tries to connect to the database?
Or are there other ways to achieve similar behaviour?
Like having two main-entrypoints? But I think AutoConfiguration will be a problem in my case.
I have the following jasypt boot integration in use:
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${jasypt-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
</dependency>
```


Is there a reason not to use the Spring integration for Jasypt which automatically decodes properties if needed?

Added the spring boot starter I am using for JASYPT.
If I did not miss something, this integration encrypts only with an identifier of DEC(value) and only with mvn and the corresponding plugin...

No it doesn't it adds a specialized PropertySource which decrypts values automatically.
